# Prove that $\sin x+2x\ge\frac{3x(x+1)}{\pi}$ for all $x\in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inequality

Question: Prove that $\sin x+2x\ge\frac{3x(x+1)}{\pi}$ for all $x\in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$

How did $\pi$ come in the expression? 
This is how I tried to solve.

$\sin x\le x$ so $\sin 2x\le 2x$

$\sin x+2x\le 3x$.

Applying AM GM inequality: $\sin x+2x\ge 2\sqrt{2x\sin x}$

$3x\ge 2\sqrt{2x\sin x}$

This how far I can go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just expanding mastrok's answer, over $I=\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ we have:
$$ \frac{d^2}{dx^2}\left(\sin x+2x\right) = -\sin x<0 \tag{1}$$
Hence $f(x)=\sin(x)+2x$ is a concave function, and since:
$$ \frac{d^2}{dx^2}\left(\frac{3}{\pi}x(x+1)\right)=\frac{6}{\pi}>0\tag{2}$$
$g(x)=\frac{3}{\pi}x(x+1)$ is a convex function. We have $f(0)=g(0)=0$ and since $\pi>2$:
$$ f\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\pi + 1>\frac{3}{2}+\frac{3\pi}{4}=g\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\tag{3}$$
proving that:
$$ \forall x\in I,\qquad f(x)>\left(2+\frac{2}{\pi}\right)x>\left(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{3}{\pi}\right)x>g(x).\tag{4}$$

Comment: double derivative is $-\sin x$ not $-\cos x$.

Answer (score 2):

$\displaystyle \sin x +2x \ge \left(2+\frac{2}{\pi}\right)x $ for $\displaystyle x\in \left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$ , Since $\sin x +2x$ is a concave function

To prove $\displaystyle \left(2+\frac{2}{\pi}\right)x\ge \frac{3x(x+1)}{\pi}$ in the range, just verify that $\displaystyle \frac{3x(x+1)}{\pi}$ is a convex function

and the inequality holds at end points.

Comment: Or just show that $2\pi+2 \ge 3(x+1)$. At $\pi/2$, $3(x+1) = 3\pi/2+3 < 2\pi+2$ because $\pi/2 > 1$.

Answer (score 2):

The $\bf{L.H.S}$ is Concave and its graph passes through $(0,0)$ and $\displaystyle \left(\frac{\pi}{2},1+\pi\right)$.

Hence it is stay above the line Connecting These $2$ points.

And $\bf{R.H.S}$ is Convex and its graph passes through $(0,0)$ and $\displaystyle \left(\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3}{2}+\frac{3\pi}{4}\right)$

Hence it is stay below the line connecting these $2$ points.

bcz $\displaystyle 1+\pi>\frac{3}{2}+\frac{3\pi}{4}$. So the first line is above the  second line , Giving the results.